Distribution of the model vs. Distribution of the Residuals
Let's say I'm going to do an analysis where my response variable has a gamma distribution. I perform the analysis pointing to the distribution in my model (eg. using the lme4 package,  m1<-glmer(Y~X1, family=Gamma(link="inverse"), data= database).
Next, to check the distribution of the residuals, shouldn't I expect a normal distribution of them and generate a qqplot with "distribution=normal"? Because if I have already adjusted the model following the distribution of the response variable, wouldn't the logic of more observations close to the model and few further away tend to generate a normal distribution of the residuals?

See the discussion in comments here

thanks @ischmidt20. reading this and other questions I found this: link, which explains more precisely what I should do and why I'm wrong with this logic of normally distributed residuals.
